Query JSON data in SQL Server
I have a SQL Server table Tbl1 with a column Col1 of nvarchar type which has the following value:
[
    {
        "value": {
            "id": "123"
        },
        "type": "Animal"
    }
]

Is it possible to query this column like where Col1.value.id = '123' and Col1.type = 'Animal'?
I tried:
SELECT *
FROM Tbl1
WHERE JSON_VALUE(Col1, '$.value.id') = '123'
  AND JSON_VALUE(Col1, '$.type') = 'Animal'

but it didn't return any value.

Your JSON is an array. Does it always have exactly one element?

You have an array, so you need to use array accessor, something like: $[0].value.id or even better openjson

Yes exactly 1 element

please provide an example with openjson

@user989988 see: Example 1 - Convert a JSON array to a temporary table

Please try the following solution.
OPENJSON() with its WITH clause is converting JSON into rectangular/relational strongly typed data. That's why we can use WHERE clause right away to filter out not needed rows.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (col) VALUES
(N'[
    {
        "value": {
            "id": "123"
        },
        "type": "Animal"
    }
]'),
(N'[
    {
        "value": {
            "id": "124"
        },
        "type": "Robot"
    }
]');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT id, u.* 
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(col)
WITH
(
   type     VARCHAR(30) '$.type',
   value_id INT         '$.value.id'
) AS u
WHERE type = 'Animal' AND value_id = 123;

Output



id
type
value_id




1
Animal
123




Reason: JSON_VALUE directly accesses JSON properties within an object but doesn't work for arrays, that is why OPENJSON is used to parse arrays. Selecting specific columns in the final output eliminates unwanted columns generated by CROSS APPLY.
Reference: Check the official documentation for JSON_VALUE and OPENJSON in SQL Server.
Updated Query:
SELECT t.id, t.col
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.col) AS json_data
WHERE JSON_VALUE(json_data.value, '$.value.id') = '123'
  AND JSON_VALUE(json_data.value, '$.type') = 'Animal';

Results:

